# how to properly use getters when sorting array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

So I'm having problems using vuex getters.

My goal is to sort the `cart` data which is an array of object by `date` using getters `myCartItems`

My problem is that after pushing the second payload `{prod_id: 2, date: Wed Nov 03 2021 10:40:20}` in my `Details` component the props['prod_id'] are logging `prod_id: 1` instead of `prod_id: 2`

**mutation**

```
addToCart: (state, payload) => {
  state.cart.push(payload) // payload = {prod_id: 1, date: Wed Nov 03 2021 10:37:26}
}
```

**getters**

```
 cartItems: (state) => {
   return state.cart.slice().sort(
      (a, b) => new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime()
    );
 },
```

**html**

```
  <div v-for="(item,index) in cartItems" :key="index">
       <Details :id="item.prod_id" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the index as the `key` is your problem since the index never changes based on sort order.

The best practice is to use a unique identifier, for example `prod_id`

```html
<div v-for="item in cartItems" :key="item.prod_id">
  <Details :id="item.prod_id" />
</div>
```